# How to handle credentials with AWS SAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, credentials, aws-sam

I'm developing an application with DB access with AWS SAM. How should I handle the credentials here? Locally, it's clear, I just have an `envvars.json` file and start the api with `sam local start-api --env-vars envvars.json`. But how can I use these environment variables in the actual deployment without saving them in the code? I would like to avoid having to enter them in the GUI for each Lambda function. Is there a possibility to open e. g. CloudFormation in the GUI and add global envvars?

P.S. I would like to avoid using AWS Secrets Manager.

Comment: Please specify what kind of database you want to connect to, because depending on the kind you could simply use IAM permissions provided by the IAM role attached to the AWS Lambda function.

Comment: Are you looking at passing in [parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) to your CloudFormation template?

Comment: You can use Parameter Store which is free, instead of Secret's Manager. CFN only supports these two services for dynamically loading parameter values.

Comment: @Dunedan That sounds promising! I would be interested to just access an SQL DB on RDS. I would also be interested, though, how to do this with DynamoDB.